# Resize form to both directions simultaneously

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I have launcher application which contains borderless full form sized FlowLayoutPanel, and loads shortcuts to it's child FlowLayoutPanels. Form should be always centered to the screen, so `ResizeEnd` event centers it.

I want that when user resizes form bigger from bottom (`this.Bottom` increases), form automatically resizes bigger from top also (`this.Top` increases).

I tried following approach (works only when resizing bigger to save code here). Yes it works, but it flickers way too much and content is jumping up and down.

```
private void Form1_ResizeBegin(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resizeStarted = true;

    top = this.Top;
    bottom = this.Bottom;
    height = this.Height;
}

private void Form1_SizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (resizeStarted)
    {
        // if resizing up, automatically resize form bigger so that bottom goes down
        if (this.Top < top)
        {
            int change = top - this.Top;
            this.Height = height + (2 * change);
        }

        // if resizing down, automatically resize form bigger and move up
        else if (this.Bottom > bottom)
        {
            int change = this.Bottom - bottom;
            this.Top = top - change;
            this.Height = height + (2 * change);
        }
    }
}

private void Form1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    resizeStarted = false;
    centerForm();
}
```

Is there any smarter way to accomplish this behaviour?

Comment: Try this.BeginUpdate() before you start the resizing and this.EndUpdate() after your resize. It might reduce flickering. Also make sure double buffering is enabled on your form.

Comment: try with `Form.CenterToScreen()` but I doubt you can get rid of the flickering

Comment: Thanks for answers, but form does not have BeginUpdate() method, only controls have it. CenterToScreen() flickers as much as my example, and form does not follow mouse cursor any more when using it alone...